# Page change callback for PagerAdapter

Tags: android, adapter

I am trying to develop an app which will display numbers 1-10 and along with it a sound for that number.

Using the example in mobile.tutsplus for horizontal swiping, I have reached to a stage where all the numbers are displayed correctly but sound for `1` will not come when we go back from `2`. (It comes initially when my activity starts with `1`). Nor will it come for `10`.

After solving the previous problem where sounds for `1` and `2` would come at once, I now understand that `instantiateItem()` will be called to pre-fetch the next entry.

I want to know at what point should I play the sound? Currently it is done in `instantiateItem()` which is why I don't hear it for `1` and `10`. I thought I could do it in `finishUpdate()` but I see it's getting called multiple times.

As per the training guide, for such a collection of objects `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` should be used and I will be trying to move to that. But I would really like to get this to work correctly.

As you'd have guessed I'm a newbie and this is my first app. I could paste the code if required.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

ViewPager has a setOnPageChangeListener() method that will allow you to set an object that gets a callback when a new page becomes the one the user is looking at.

something like this will get you on the right path:

```
mPageChangeListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
        playSoundForPage(pos);
    }

};
yourViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(mPageChangeListener);
```

however you'll have to put this in whatever owns your ViewPager (activity, or fragment) and not your Adapter.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was suspecting setOnPageChangeListener() to be the one, but was not sure how to use it in the Adapter. Will try your method.

Comment: Did it a little differently.. private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: `setOnPageChangeListener` is deprecated. Use `addOnPageChangeListener` instead.